# How can I reproduce data in numpy with random.choice?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a labeled dataset:

```
data = np.array([5.2, 4, 5, 2, 5.3, 10, 0])
labels = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4])
```

I want to pick the data `5.2, 5 and 5.3` with the label 1 and reproduce it, like followed:

```
datalabel1 = data[(labels == 1)]
```

Then I want to do a `random.choice()`, for example (pseudo):

```
# indices are the indices from label 1
random_choices = np.random.choice(indices, size = 5)
```

And get as output different values with different indices:

```
# indices are the different indices of the data from the pool out of random choice
data:    [5.3 5.2 5.2 5.2 5]
indices: [4 0 0 2 2]
```

My goal is to pick out of a pool with label 1 data.

Comment: What is `indices` in `np.random.choice(indices, size = 5)`? Also what does `[0 2 0 4 2]` means? Please edit your question for better clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`labels == 1` is a boolean mask. You nee to apply it to `data`, not back to `labels` to get the data elements labeled 1:

```
np.random.choice(data[labels == 1], ...)
```

You can also convert `labels == 1` to a set of indices and choose on those *before* indexing:

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(labels == 1)
data[np.random.choice(indices, ...)]
```